# Corregir una palabra en java

Tags: java, netbeans

Estoy haciendo un programa en `java` que tiene que comprobar que una palabra este bien escrita, solo las palabras que tienen **np** y las corrija a **mp** y las palabras que contengan **nb** no deben ser corregidas.

Hice 3 arreglos, uno contiene el alfabeto menos las letras **n,p,m,b** y en los otros dos arreglos agregue la **mp** y la **nb**, para que se realice la comparación, pero al introducir una cadena que tenga mas de una **n** ya no la corrige.

Por ejemplo la palabra **conplexion** tendría que corregirse a **complexion** pero como hay mas de una **n**, no la corrige.

```
      for(int i=0;i<entrada.length();i++){
            for(int con=0;con<alfabeto.length;con++){
                    if(entrada.charAt(i)==alfabeto[con]){         
                         m++;
                    } 
            }} if(m>1){  
           for(int i=0;i<entrada.length();i++){
            for(int con=0;con<letras.length;con++){
                    if(entrada.charAt(i)==letras[con]){
                    n++;
                    }  
    }

                  }}
            if(n>1){
                   String Str = new String(entrada); 
                   lblResultado2.setText(Str.replaceFirst("MP","NP"));
            }else{

                String Str = new String(entrada);  
                lblResultado2.setText(Str.replaceFirst("NP","MP"));
            }
```

}

Comment: La diferencia es que replaceFirst() solo reemplaza la primera coinicidencia, mientras que usando replace() reemplaza todas las coincidencias en la cadena.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope. Deberías usar lo siguiente:

```
String my_str = "conplexion";

String my_new_str = my_str.replace("np", "mp");

System.out.println(my_new_str);

//Salida: complexion
```

Comment: Hola podrías añadir una explicación de tu código?

Answer (score 2):

El método [replaceFirst()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceFirst-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-)  únicamente reemplaza la primera coincidencia en la cadena, revisa la documentación:

> [replaceFirst()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceFirst-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-) : Reemplaza la primera subcadena de esta cadena
>   que coincide con la expresión regular dada con el reemplazo dado.

Ejemplo:

```
String s = "HolaMPAdrianaMP";
System.out.println(s.replaceFirst("MP","NP")
```

Salida:

```
HolaNPAdrianaMP
```

Lo que deseas realizar es reemplazar todas las coincidencias lo cual puedes realizar mediante el método

> **[replace(char oldChar, char newChar)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace-char-char-)** : Devuelve una cadena
>   resultante de reemplazar todas las apariciones de oldChar en esta
>   cadena con newChar.

Ejemplo:

```
String s = "HolaMPAdrianaMP";
System.out.println(s.replace("MP","NP")
```

Salida:

```
HolaNPAdrianaNP
```

---

Reemplaza el método a usar en tu código:

```
...
...
if(n>1){
       String Str = new String(entrada); 
       lblResultado2.setText(Str.replace("MP","NP"));
}else{
    String Str = new String(entrada);  
    lblResultado2.setText(Str.replace("NP","MP"));
}
...
...
```